# Sherman-Morrison formula for non-invertible bmatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse, graph-laplacian

I am trying to find an expression for inverse of the following matrix

> $(L+\frac{1}{n}J)$

Where $L$ is the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Laplacian_matrix_for_simple_graphs) of a simple, connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, and $J=11^T$ is the all $1$ matrix. It is known that $L$ is singular, while the above matrix is non-singular. Does there exist some formula akin to [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) for this kind of inverse computation?